# Call JavaScript function on DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged Event:

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu

I have written one JavaScript function as follows:

```
 function CalcTotalAmt() 
 {
    ----------
    -----------
 }
```

I have one DropDownList,

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I need to call the above JavaScript function in the DropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged Event.
I tried like below;

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddl.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return CalcTotalAmt();");
}
```

But the JavaScript function is not executing.
How to call the JavaScript function in DropDownList Change Event?

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but are you sure you even want to cause a postback here? If all your server side code is doing is calling the client side code, then why not just leave the server out of it and run it directly on the client side?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**First Method: (Tested)**

Code in .aspx.cs:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ddl.Attributes.Add("onchange", "CalcTotalAmt();");
        }
    }

    protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Your Code
    }
```

JavaScript function: return true from your JS function

```
   function CalcTotalAmt() 
 {
//Your Code
 }
```

.aspx code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="a"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="b"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

**Second Method: (Tested)**

Code in .aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"].Equals("ddlchange"))
                ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ddl.Attributes.Add("onchange", "CalcTotalAmt();");
            }
        }

        protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Your Code
        }
```

JavaScript function: return true from your JS function

```
function CalcTotalAmt() {
         //Your Code
     __doPostBack("ctl00$MainContent$ddl","ddlchange");
 }
```

.aspx code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="a"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="b"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: the Javascript function is executing.. But i have written some coding in selectedindexchanged event. But that event is not firing.. how to solve this problem?

Comment: But when I click some event, then at first the selectedIndexChanged event is firing and then the corresponding event is firing. I dont know why it is happening like this?

Answer (score 18):

Or you can do it like as well:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" onchange="javascript:CalcTotalAmt();" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: and if you want to fire that event during server side change event of drop down, than try by registering your script through Page.RegisterStartUpScript method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript();` to call any of your javascript event/Client Event from the server. For example, to display a message using javascript's `alert();`, you can do this:

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.write("<script>alert('This is my message');</script>");
 //----or alternatively and to be more proper
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "callJSFunction", "alert('This is my message')", true);
}
```

To be exact for you, do this...

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "callJSFunction", "CalcTotalAmt();", true);
}
```