# The gridview is not filtered based on a pre selected value in a A dropdownlist using the model binding of the feature in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, model-binding

**Note: This is ASP.NET Web Forms Model Binding in .NET 4.5 and NOT MVC**

I'm  using  the  feature in ASP.NET 4.5 of the  model binding  to bind a dropdownlist and gridview  in a webform (not MVC) to methods in DAL and it's working fine as described in [filtering data with model binding and web forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/sorting-paging-and-filtering-data)

The dropdownlist :

```
 AutoPostBack="True"
```

I tried to set an initial value in the dropdownlist using the following java script:

```
    <script>
        function setSelectedValue(s, v) {
            for (var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++) {
                if (s.options[i].text == v) {
                    s.options[i].selected = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('ddlDates'), "somevalue");
    </script>
```

The initial value is ok.

It's supposed that the gridview is refreshed (filtered) based  on that value when the form is first loaded, but  that is not happened.

It's filtered only when you pick a value from dropdownlist.

What I missed to auto refresh the gridview when the WebForm is initially loaded?

**Update**

The Question Is Completely different than [Error when modifying ASP.NET DropDownList with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995880/error-when-modifying-asp-net-dropdownlist-with-javascript)

I have no errors and the problem is related to data binding feature in asp.net WebForm 4.5 behaviour at start of form.

I removed the java Script code, and used declarative declaration:

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDateId" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control"
                SelectMethod="GetMyDropDownItems"
                 SelectedValue="<%# GetDefault()  %>"
                AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                ItemType="Store.merit"
                SelectMethod="GetMerits"
              CssClass="table table-striped">               
            </asp:GridView>
```

*Code behind*

```
     public IEnumerable<string> GetMyDropDownItems()
            {
                //Call DAL methods and return IEnumerable<string>
            }

        //note the [Control] Attribute that use the ddl ddlDateId

      public IEnumerable<Merit> GetMerits([Control] string ddlDateId)
            {
                 //Call DAL methods and return IEnumerable<Merit>
            }
```

**At start of form loading:**

The ddl is OK filled with data , the default value is Ok
The grid view is empty

The Datagrid is empty  means that the parameter 'ddlDateId' that is passed to the  method 'GetMerits' is null, but really it has a value.

Even if I removed  the default value  expression `SelectedValue="<%# GetDefault()  %>"`, and using the first item in the ddl , the grid view is empty

**When selecting item**

In selecting item from the list (ddl) the gridview is refreshed and working fine.

So, the question is why Asp.net framework pass null value(and really not)  to the Select method of gridView At the Start Of Form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when modifying ASP.NET DropDownList with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995880/error-when-modifying-asp-net-dropdownlist-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in the back end. Try setting up the selected value in backend where you are binding DDL. And then call `gridBind(DDL.selectedvalue)` on `pageLoad()`

Comment: The value of ddl is passed to the back end via the parameter of the binding method. The gridview is binded using the `SelectMethod` (no datasource is used). The root problem is no PostBack from the ddl when the form is loaded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173914/difference-betwwen-autopostback-true-and-autopostback-false

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861895/call-javascript-function-on-dropdownlist-selectedindexchanged-event